# Entity Framework query similar to raw SQL query with order by date where null comes last

Tags: c#, entity-framework

l have a query

```
SELECT *
  FROM [ExcelDumps].[dbo].[ProductPrice] As p
  Where  
   ( 
    p.[EndDate] >= '2018-12-18' 
    OR
    p.[EndDate] is null 
   ) 
   order by case when p.[EndDate] is null then 2 else 1 end, p.[EndDate] asc
```

what am trying to achieve is it possible to achieve the same results using Entity Framework where priority is lastly given to p.[EndDate]

the desired output is as follows :

what l have done

```
 using (var cod = new ExcelDumpsEntities1())
            {
                var list = cod.ProductPrices.Where(c => c.EndDate >= c.EndDate || c.EndDate == null)
                                            .OrderBy(c => c.EndDate)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

                var sqlQuery = @"SELECT Top 1 *
                                  FROM [ExcelDumps].[dbo].[ProductPrice] As p
                                  Where  
                                   ( 
                                    p.[EndDate] >= '2018-12-18' 
                                    OR
                                    p.[EndDate] is null 
                                   ) 
                                   order by case when p.[EndDate] is null then 2 else 1 end, p.[EndDate]  asc ";
                var sqlRaw = cod.ProductPrices.SqlQuery(sqlQuery) 
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I don't want to use SQL query or stored procedure but must do it in like LINQ to entities

this question is based on this question on dba [sql query here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226679/select-within-or-closest-to-date-range-mssql/226695#226695)

How can l do that in Entity Framework

Comment: You can use two queries and union the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var filterDate = new DateTime("2018-12-18");
var result = cod.ProductPrices.Where(c => c.EndDate >= filterDate || c.EndDate == null)     
     .OrderBy(c => c.EndDate == null)
     .ThenBy(c => c.EndDate);
```

If you want to execute the query immediately you might want to add an .ToList() in the end. Otherwise it will be executed when it is used.